# AWS Pre-signed URL return 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file with presigned AWS url.

I generate a presigned url like that :

```
use AsyncAws\S3\S3Client;
$s3          = new S3Client();
$bucket      = 'my-bucket';
$key         = 'myfile.pdf';
$date        = new \DateTimeImmutable('+15minutes');
$contentType = 'application/pdf';

$input = new GetObjectRequest([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $key,
            'ContentType' => $contentType
        ]);
$presignUrl = $s3->presign($input, $date);
```

This code above works fine, I get a presigned url like this : "https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/myfile.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220809T141153Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2F20220809%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&x-amz-content-sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Next, I try to use this url to upload a file with Postman.

I select my pdf file via Body / binary / Select file

This is my postman config and response :
[image: Put postman]

As you can see, I have a 403 code response.

These are my headers (of course I've tried with differents Content-Type but nothing better than the exactly same 403 response.

[image: headers postman]

Important information : With the same $s3 instance and authentification, if I try to get object url ($content = $s3->getObject($input); with AsyncAws), it works well. So I suppose, it is not an authentification issue.

Thanks in advance if you have any idea for me !

Comment: That's a GetObject signed URL. You can't use it for upload.

Comment: Use [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/mediastoredata/model/PutObjectRequest.html) for a PUT request.

Comment: This GetObject was in the middle of my noise and I didn't see it. Thank you very much both of you, it works, you saved my day :)